# Sphinx - How to change formatting style for function arguments

Tags: python, pdf, formatting, python-sphinx

I'm generating documentation of my python code as pdf using sphinx.

Some of my functions are a bit longer and contain several arguments

ex.

```
custom_module.descriptive_function_name(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5)
```

**Currently**, sphinx renders this function like this which tends to jam everything to the right side of the page and sometimes also introduces breaks within parameter names

```
custom_module.descriptive_function_name(arg1,
                                        arg2,
                                        ar-
                                        g3,
                                        arg4,
                                        arg5)
```

**What I would like is more like the K&R brace style**

```
custom_modue.descriptive_function_name(
    arg1,
    arg2,
    arg3,
    arg4,
    arg5,
)
```

Is there a way to get sphinx to render like this? I checked a few options for directives but I didn't notice anything related to this.

Thanks,

Comment: I should also mention that I'm generating a pdf.

Comment: I am not aware of any solutions. PDF (LaTeX) output is mentioned in a comment here: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/1514.